# Using ng-repeat to build a list of checkboxes, that submit to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have an app where I call for a list of businesses from the server, which I display as checkboxes in my view, using ng-repeat:

```
     <md-checkbox 
       ng-repeat="business in businesses" 
       ng-model="business.$index" 
       value="business._id"
       aria-label="Checkbox"
       >
        {{business.business_name}}
     </md-checkbox>
```

My challenge is trying to update an object/array in my controller, where I can send an updated list of IDs to the server.

For some reason when I click on one of the checkboxes they all get selected.

Would love to know how others:

1)dynamically generate a number of checkboxes from an object array pulled from a service.

2)display them in the view, then pass the checked status of the checkboxes back to the controller.

I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm just not making any progress.

Comment: please provide the structure of `businesses` variable

Answer (score 0):

Add a `selected` property to your objects init by default to false (if you want your checkboxes not selected by default).
Your property will be true when checked, false otherwise.

```
<md-checkbox 
       ng-repeat="business in businesses track by business._id"
       ng-init="business['selected']=false;" 
       ng-model="business['selected']" 
       aria-label="Checkbox"
       >
        {{business.business_name}}
     </md-checkbox>
```

From your controller, if you loop inside your `businesses` array, you will have within each object property `selected` true or false, in order to know if they are selected or not, and if selected just access the `_id` of that object. 
For example you can have all the selected items of your array in this way inside your controller:

```
console.log($scope.businesses.filter(el => el.selected));
```

Answer (score 0):

*assuming `md-checkbox` behaves like a checkbox...*

```
 <md-checkbox 
   ng-repeat="business in businesses" 
   ng-model="business.$index" 
   value="business._id"
   aria-label="Checkbox">
    {{business.business_name}}
 </md-checkbox>
```

`business.$index` would evaluate to something like `business.3` which is not valid and probably not what you're expecting.

you could use something like `business.selected` as quirimmo suggested.

this would make the checkmark unchecked if `selected` is undefined or false and when we check the checkbox, it would set `selected` to true.

on the other end, when you want to save those selections, you will have to make sure your controller is looking for the `selected` property.